# Diff between the datatypes decimal(1, 1) and numeric (1, 1) in sql

Tags: sql

Can anyone please explain the difference between the datatypes decimal(1, 1) and numeric (1, 1) in SQL with an example?

Comment: In **SQL Server**, the types `decimal` and `numeric` are **equivalent** - no difference

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do at least 1 Google search prior to posting, especially if it is something as concrete as a definition of data types.

Comment: Same thing, according to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference, NUMERIC and DECIMAL are synonyms:[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)